# Laravel Route Binding Model Undefined offset: 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2. I have a model called Book then try to move the route binding model from my controller to RouteServiceProvider.php

here is my route binding model before i move it to the RouteServiceProvider.php

```
$book = Book::findOrFail($id);
```

after (in my RouteServiceProvider.php)

```
$router->model('book', 'App\Book');
```

It works prefectly before i move it to the RouteServiceProvider, but now it throw me an error eveytime i try to **update**, (create and store works fine).

It failed to update the input to the database, but when i try to debug using `dd($this->method());` in the top of my rules on request, it say "PATCH"

the error is **Undefined offset: 9** ...framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php line 1461: `$extra[$segments[$i]] = $segments[$i + 1];`

I assume the error is from my update controller `return view('dashboards.book', compact('book'));` or mybe from the request conditional for the patch/update method

Here is the complete code

#### Controller@update

```
public function update(Book $book, BookRequest $request)
{
    //$book = Book::findOrFail($id);  move to the RouteServiceProvider

    $input = $request->all();

    $book->update($request->all());

    //return view('dashboards.book');
    return view('dashboards.book', compact('book'));

}
```

#### BookRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class BookRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {

        //$book = $this->route('book');

        //$this->route()->parameter('books');

        //dd($this->method());



        // Check Create or Update
        if ($this->method() == 'POST') {
            $label_rules = 'required|string|size:6|unique:books,label,';
            $isbn_rules = 'sometimes|string|size:10|unique:books,isbn,';
        }

        else {
            $label_rules = 'required|string|size:6|unique:books,label,' .$this->route()->parameter('book'); 
            $isbn_rules = 'sometimes|string|size:10|unique:books,isbn,' .$this->route()->parameter('book');
        }




        return [
            'judul'             => 'required|string|max:100',
            'label'             => $label_rules,
            'isbn'              => $isbn_rules,
            'tanggal_terbit'    => 'required|date',
            'status'            => 'required|in:tersedia,dipinjam,hilang,rusak',
            'id_penulis'        => 'required',
            'id_penerbit'       => 'required',
            'id_kategori'       => 'required',
        ];


    }
}
```

#### RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        //

        parent::boot($router);

        // route model binding
        $router->model('book', 'App\Book');
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
}
```

The Errors

```
in Validator.php line 1461
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 9', 'E:\YUDY\WEB PROJECT\CLIENTS\perpus lab\testroutemodelbinding\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php', '1461', array('segments' => array('label:"099187"', 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"', 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1', 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1', 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"', 'updated_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"}'), 'extra' => array('label:"099187"' => 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"' => 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1' => 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1' => 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"'), 'count' => '9', 'i' => '8')) in Validator.php line 1461
at Validator->getExtraConditions(array('label:"099187"', 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"', 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1', 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1', 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"', 'updated_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"}')) in Validator.php line 1379
at Validator->getUniqueExtra(array('books', 'label', '{"id":15', 'judul:"Fast And Furious"', 'label:"099187"', 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"', 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1', 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1', 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"', 'updated_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"}')) in Validator.php line 1338
at Validator->validateUnique('label', '099187', array('books', 'label', '{"id":15', 'judul:"Fast And Furious"', 'label:"099187"', 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"', 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1', 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1', 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"', 'updated_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"}'), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 485
at Validator->validate('label', 'Unique') in Validator.php line 425
at Validator->passes() in ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php line 24
at FormRequest->validate() in FoundationServiceProvider.php line 41
at FoundationServiceProvider->Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}(object(BookRequest), object(Application)) in Container.php line 1031
at Container->fireCallbackArray(object(BookRequest), array(object(Closure))) in Container.php line 994
at Container->fireResolvingCallbacks('App\Http\Requests\BookRequest', object(BookRequest)) in Container.php line 648
at Container->make('App\Http\Requests\BookRequest', array()) in Application.php line 697
at Application->make('App\Http\Requests\BookRequest') in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 85
at ControllerDispatcher->transformDependency(object(ReflectionParameter), array('book' => object(Book)), array('book' => object(Book))) in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 58
at ControllerDispatcher->resolveMethodDependencies(array('book' => object(Book)), object(ReflectionMethod)) in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 41
at ControllerDispatcher->resolveClassMethodDependencies(array('book' => object(Book)), object(DashboardController), 'update') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 143
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(DashboardController), object(Route), 'update') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(DashboardController), object(Route), object(Request), 'update') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController', 'update') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('E:\YUDY\WEB PROJECT\CLIENTS\perpus lab\testroutemodelbinding\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Any suggestion for the error?

Comment: Could you provide us the full stack trace of the problem?

Comment: @sisve Hi thanks for the response, kindly check the my question update

Comment: Why does your $label_rules and $isbn_rules end with a comma on posts? `$this->route()->parameter('book')` will probably return a Book instance with model binding, not a specific id.

Comment: i'm not sure about that, maybe i copy the rules from the controller before i move it to the BookRequest.  refering to the laravel doc Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID: "'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id". by the way i try to delete the coma but i throw me to another error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number..`

Answer (score 1):

Your validation rules previously assumed that the route segment was an identifier. With model binding now active, it returns a model instance instead.

```
$label_rules = 'required|string|size:6|unique:books,label,' . 
                    $this->route()->parameter('book');
```

This can be seen in your stack trace.

```
in Validator.php line 1461
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 9', 'E:\YUDY\WEB PROJECT\CLIENTS\perpuslab\testroutemodelbinding\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php', '1461', array('segments' => array('label:"099187"', 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"', 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1', 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1', 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"', 'updated_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"}'), 'extra' => array('label:"099187"' => 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"' => 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1' => 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1' => 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"'), 'count' => '9', 'i' => '8')) in Validator.php line 1461
at Validator->getExtraConditions(array('label:"099187"', 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"', 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1', 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1', 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"', 'updated_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"}')) in Validator.php line 1379
at Validator->getUniqueExtra(array('books', 'label', '{"id":15', 'judul:"Fast And Furious"', 'label:"099187"', 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"', 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1', 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1', 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"', 'updated_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"}')) in Validator.php line 1338
at Validator->validateUnique('label', '099187', array('books', 'label', '{"id":15', 'judul:"Fast And Furious"', 'label:"099187"', 'isbn:"9918892810"', 'tanggal_terbit:"2018-02-10"', 'status:"tersedia"', 'id_penerbit:1', 'id_kategori:1', 'id_penulis:1', 'created_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"', 'updated_at:"2018-01-02 00:01:26"}'), object(Validator)) in Validator.php line 485
at Validator->validate('label', 'Unique') in Validator.php line 425
```

The unique validation rule supports several parameters, and what you attempt to pass in as id is really a `{"id":15'` (initial part of the array before the first comma), then a primary key column `'judul:"Fast And Furious"'`, followed by attempts to parse the rest of the entries as extra conditions. They are supposed to come in pairs (`column,value,column,value,...`), but in your case there are only 7 entries left in the array, an uneven number. Thus the failure.

Comment: do you mean i have to remove the comma?

Comment: No, I am saying that `$this->route()->parameter('book')` returns a Book instance, and not the identifier you expect. You have to read the id from the Book instance if you want it.